# counting omer for shavuot

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer

God commanded: "And you shall count for yourself from the morrow of the Shabbat... seven complete weeks... seven weeks you shall count... 50 days (Vayikra 23:15,16)."

1. If it says 'for yourself', then why does it say the Omer was brought by one person?
2. Was the Korban Omer offered every day of the seven weeks (at the time of the temple)? If it was only offered once, then why do we recite Sefirat HaOmer every day?

Comment: 1. It doesn't say "for yourself": it says "for yourselves".  2. What is "it" that says the _omer_ was brought by one person? 3. Why do you think the number of times the _oner_ was brought should affect the number of times we count?

Comment: 4. What's the contradiction between "count for yourself" and the _omer_'s being brought by one person?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38146/759

Answer (score 2):

1. The Korban Omer, like any communal sacrifice, was brought from the community funds.
2. The Korban HaOmer was brought on the sixteenth of Nissan. Sefirat HaOmer, a separate Mitzvah, applies for all seven weeks. The term 'Sefirat HaOmer' is not used in Vayikra (Leviticus); it probably came to be because the first day of the count is the day of the bringing of the Omer.

Comment: Why are you so sure the Mitzva of counting is separate? [Many Rishonim](http://etzion.org.il/en/salt-monday-24-nisan-5776-omer-9-may-2-2016) thought it only applies when an Omer was brought.