# How many Mitzvos does the Mishnah cover?

Tags: halacha-theory, number, mitzvah, mishna

How many (out of the 613 Deoraytah) Mitzvos are explicitly discussed in the 6 Sdarim of the Mishah (not including those that are only mentioned tangentially, like Kibud Av at the beginning of Peah)?

Comment: The parenthetical addition seems to limit your question to a simple answer. There are 63 tractates so that covers almost 63 mitzvot, if you were to correlate each masechta to oen mitzvah. Of course, that doesn't work exactly, as, e.g. Bava Kamma doesn't correlate to a specific mitzvah. Neither does Avot, for that matter.

Comment: It's a machlokes what the 613 are. Are you asking according to a specific opinion?

Comment: @DanF Many masechtos deal entirely with Rabbinic institutions, like Yadayim, and many deal with multiple Biblical commandments, like Yevamos which deals with Arayos, Yibbum, Geirus, Chalitzah, etc.

Comment: [It covers however many it covers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95024/13438): *The only correct way to count mitzvot is to go through the Torah and Talmud and analyze each case individually to determine whether something is a mitzvah or not. Whatever number we have at the end of the entire analysis is the number of mitzvot, and that number can theoretically be anything.*

Comment: IIRC Kibud Av is discussed at length - e.g. in Kidushin.

Answer (score 8):

The only real answer to this question can come from going through the list and finding a mishnah for each mitzvah.  I was hoping this had been done before, but if it has, nobody here has found it.  So, unless someone does, we can put it together ourselves.  Please contribute!

For each mitzvah, please put either

- a mishnah citation, with Sefaria links encouraged but not required because it's a ton of work to do so many
- **[?]** if you don't know if and/or where there's a citation
- **[x]**, with a possible explanation, if you're sure there's no Mishnah citation
- **[b]**, with explanation, if it's borderline

Here is the list, following the order of [Sefer haChinuch](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaChinukh.1.1).

1. Having children: Yevamos 6:6
2. Milah: [Shabbos 19](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Shabbat.19)
3. Gid Hanasheh: Chullin 7
4. Kiddush Hachodesh: Rosh Hashana 1:1-3:1
5. Shechting the Pesach: Pesachim 5-6 and a few more
6. Eating the Pesach: Pesachim 2:8, the end of chapter 7, and the end of chapter 10, for example, describe how you eat it.  But I can't think of an explicit statement that each individual has to actually eat a kezayis. **[b]**
7. Not eating the Pesach raw or cooked: Pesachim 2:8 and 7:1-2
8. Not leaving the Pesach over: Pesachim 7:11
9. Getting rid of chametz: First few chapters of Pesachim
10. Eating matzah: Pesachim 2:5
11. Bal yimmatzei: First few chapters of Pesachim, explicit statement in 3:3
12. Not eating food with chametz in it: Pesachim 3:1
13. Not giving the Pesach to a heretic: **[?]**
14. Not giving the Pesach to a non-Jew: Pesachim 8:8
15. Not taking the Pesach out of the group: Pesachim 7:12-13
16. Not breaking a bone of the Pesach: Pesachim 7:11-12
17. Not eating the Pesach uncircumcised: Possibly hinted to in Pesachim 8:8 **[b]** but there might be a clearer reference somewhere in Kodshim **[?]**
18. Sanctifying firstborn: Bechoros, don't know it well enough for an exact citation **[?]**
19. Not eating chametz: First few chapters of Pesachim, explicit statement in 3:5
20. Bal yeira'eh: First few chapters of Pesachim, explicit statement in 2:2 and 3:3
21. Telling the story of Yetzias Mitzrayim: Pesachim 10:4-6
22. Redeeming a firstborn donkey: Bechoros 1
23. Breaking the neck of a firstborn donkey if you don't redeem it: Bechoros 1:7
24. Not going outside the techum on Shabbos: Eiruvin 3-5
25. Belief in G-d: Sanhedrin 10:1, I guess?  It's not as explicit as I'd like.  Maybe there's another citation somewhere else **[?]**
26. Not believing in idols: same as 25 **[?]**
27. Not *making* an idol: A"Z 3:1
28. Not bowing to an idol: Sanhedrin 7:6
29. Not serving an idol in the standard way: Sanhedrin 7:6
30. Not swearing falsely/unnecessarily: Shevuos 3
31. Making kiddush on Shabbos: Berachos 8:1
32. Not doing work on Shabbos: Just about all of Shabbos and large parts of Eiruvin
33. Respecting parents: Peah 1:1, Kiddushin 1:7
34. Not murdering: Shabbos 23:5, Sanhedrin 9:1-2
35. Not comitting adultery: Yevamos 3:10
36. Not kidnapping: Sanhedrin 11:1
37. Not testifying falsely: Makkos 1:3
38. Not desiring other people's things: Avot 4:21
39. Not making a human figure: **[?]**
40. Not building the mizbeach out of stones cut with iron: Middos 3:4
41. Not going up to the mizbeach on stairs: **[?]**
42. Halachos of a Jewish servant: Kiddushin 1:2
43. Marriage of a Jewish maidservant: Bechoros 1:7
44. Redeeming a Jewish maidservant: Bechoros 1:7
45. Not reselling a Jewish maidservant: **[?]**
46. Not depriving your wife of food, clothing, and intimacy: **[?]**
47. Killing someone who is liable to death by choking: Sanhedrin 7:1,3, 11:1
48. Not hitting your parents: Yevamos 2:5
49. Beis Din judging cases of human damage: Bava Kama 2:6, 8
50. Killing someone who is liable to death by beheading: Sanhedrin 7:1,3, 9:1
51. Beis Din judging cases of keren animal damage: Bava Kama 1-5
52. Not eating the meat of an ox that's supposed to be stoned: Bava Kama 4:8
53. Beis Din judging cases of pit damage: Bava Kama 3, 5:5
54. Beis Din judging cases of robbery: Bava Kama 9-10
55. Beis Din judging cases of shein and regel animal damage: Bava Kama 2:2
56. Beis Din judging cases of fire damage: Bava Kama 6:5
57. Beis Din judging cases of shomer chinam: Bava Metsi'a 7:8
58. Beis Din judging cases where someone claims money from someone else: Bava Metsi'a 1:1, etc.
59. Beis Din judging cases of shomer sachar and socheir: Bava Metsi'a 7:8
60. Beis Din judging cases of sho'eil: Bava Metsi'a 7:8
61. Beis Din judging cases of seduction: Kesubos 3
62. Not allowing people who do sorcery to live: Sanhedrin 7:4
63. Not bullying a convert verbally: Bava Metzia 4:10
64. Not bullying a convert monetarily: **[?]**
65. Not torturing a widow or orphan: **[?]**
66. Lending to poor people: **[?]**
67. Not demanding repayment from a poor person who doesn't have it: **[?]**
68. Not borrowing or lending with interest: Bava Metsi'a 5
69. Not cursing a judge: **[?]**
70. Not cursing G-d: Sanhedrin 7:5
71. Not cursing a leader: **[?]**
72. Not separating agricultural portions out of order: Terumos 3:6-7
73. Not eating a treifah: Chulin 2-3
74. Not listening to one claimant's arguments when the other one isn't there: **[?]**
75. Not letting sinners testify: Rosh Hashana 1:8, Sanhedrin 3:3
76. Not following a one-judge majority to kill someone: Sanhedrin 4:1
77. Not changing your mind from innocence to guilt in a capital case: Sanhedrin 4:1
78. Following the majority: Sanhedrin 1:6
79. Not favoring a poor person in judgment: Kesubos 9:2-3, maybe somewhere in Nezikin too **[?]**
80. Taking the load off a tired animal: Bava Metsi'a 2:10
81. Not disfavoring a bad person in judgement: **[?]**
82. Not executing someone without witnesses: Sanhedrin somewhere **[?]**
83. Not taking bribes: Peah 8:9, probably somewhere in Nezikin too **[?]**
84. Dealing appropriately with Sheviis produce: Sheviis 6-9
85. Resting on Shabbos: Just about all of Shabbos and most of Eiruvin.  I can't think of an exact citation for the asei in particular, but it doesn't have all that many nafka minahs (see Minchas Chinuch) **[b]**
86. Not swearing by an idol: **[?]**
87. Not causing Jews to serve idols: **[?]**
88. Bringing a Chagigah on the regel: Chagigah 1:1-2:3
89. Not shechting the Pesach while you have chametz: Pesachim 5:4
90. Not leaving the fats of the Pesach over: Pesachim 5:10 describes burning them **[b]** but probably there's a better one in Kodshim **[?]**
91. Bikkurim: Most of Bikkurim
92. Not cooking meat with milk: Chullin 8
93. Not entering treaties with idol worshipers: **[?]**
94. Not allowing idol worship in our land: **[?]**
95. Building the Beis Hamikdash: Middos, not sure if there's a precise statement of the mitzvah **[?]**
96. Not taking out the poles of the Aron: **[?]**
97. Putting the lechem hapanim and levonah: Menachos somewhere **[?]**
98. Lighting the lamps of the Menorah: **[?]**
99. Wearing bigdei kehunah: Yoma 7:8
100. Not letting the choshen bounce around: **[?]**
101. Not tearing the me'il: **[?]**
102. Eating the meat of a chatas and asham: **[?]**
103. Bringing ketores: **[?]**
104. Not bringing wrong things on the gold Mizbeiach: **[?]**
105. Giving the half shekel every year: Shekalim 1-2
106. Washing hands and feet to serve in the Beis Hamikdash: Tamid 1:4
107. Anointing the Kohen Gadol and king with the shemen hamishchah: **[?]**
108. Not annointing anyone else with it: Kereitot 1:1
109. Not making duplicate shemen hamishchah: Kereitot 1:1
110. Not making duplicate ketores: Kereitot 1:1
111. Not eating idol sacrifices: **[?]**
112. Not working during Sheviis: Sheviis 1-5
113. Not eating meat cooked with milk: Chulin 8
114. Not executing people on Shabbos: Shabbos 7:2 **[b]**
115. Doing an olah correctly: Zevachim **[?]**
116. Doing a mincha correctly: Menachos **[?]**
117. Not bringing chametz or honey on the Mizbeyach: **[?]**
118. Not bringing an offering without salt: **[?]**
119. Salting offerings: **[?]**
120. Bringing a par he'elem davar: Horayos/Zevachim **[?]**
121. Bringing a chatas: Zevachim/Kerisos **[?]**
122. Testifying in beis din: Rosh Hashana 1:1-3:1, Sanhedrin/Makkos somewhere **[?]**
123. Bringing an oleh veyoreid: **[?]**
124. Not separating a bird chatas: Zevachim **[?]**
125. Not putting oil on a minchas chotei: Menachos **[?]**
126. Not putting levonah on a minchas chotei: Menachos **[?]**
127. Adding 25% in paying back me'ilah: Me'ilah **[?]**
128. Bringing an asham taluy: Zevachim/Kerisos **[?]**
129. Bringing an asham vadai: Zevachim **[?]**
130. Returning stolen property: **[?]**
131. Terumas hadeshen: Yoma 2:1-2, probably in Tamid too **[?]**
132. Putting wood on the fire: Yoma 4:6, Taanis 4:5, Shekalim 6:5-6, probably the primary location is Tamid **[?]**
133. Not putting out the fire on the Mizbeyach: **[?]**
134. Kohanim eating the remainder of the menachos: Menachos **[?]**
135. Not making the remainder of the menachos chametz: Menachos **[?]**
136. Bringing the chavitin: Megillah 1:9, Menachos **[?]**
137. Not eating the mincha of a Kohen: Menachos **[?]**
138. Doing a chatas correctly: Zevachim **[?]**
139. Not eating a chatas that was brought in the Heichal: Zevachim **[?]**
140. Doing an asham correctly: Zevachim **[?]**
141. Doing a shelamim correctly: Zevachim **[?]**
142. Not leaving over the meat of a todah: Pesachim 7:11 for the Pesach **[b]**, probably a better one in Zevachim **[?]**
143. Burning nosar: Pesachim 7:10 describes it for the Pesach **[b]**, probably a better one in Zevachim **[?]**
144. Not eating piggul: **[?]**
145. Not eating kodshim that are tamei: **[?]**
146. Burning kodshim that are tamei: Pesachim 7:8-9 for the Pesach, maybe also in Zevachim **[?]**
147. Not eating cheilev: Chulin somewhere **[?]**, special case in Bikkurim 2:10
148. Not eating blood: Chulin somewhere **[?]**
149. Not going into the Beis Hamikdash with unkempt hair: **[?]**
150. Not going into the Beis Hamikdash with torn clothes: **[?]**
151. Not leaving the Beis Hamikdash while serving: **[?]**
152. Not going into the Beis Hamikdash or issuing a halachic ruling when drunk: **[?]**
153. Checking the kosher signs of land animals: Chulin **[?]**
154. Not eating non-kosher land animals: Chulin **[?]**
155. Checking the kosher signs of fish: Chulin **[?]**
156. Not eating non-kosher fish: Chulin **[?]**
157. Not eating non-kosher birds: Chulin **[?]**
158. Checking the kosher signs of grasshoppers: Chulin **[?]**
159. Tum'ah of sheratzim: **[?]**
160. Tum'ah of food: Huge parts of Tahoros, Machshirin, and Uktzin
161. Tum'ah of a neveilah: **[?]**, special case in Bikkurim 2:11
162. Not eating sheratzim on land: **[?]**
163. Not eating bugs in fruits: **[?]**
164. Not eating sheratzim in the sea: **[?]**
165. Not eating sheratzim that grow on dead things: **[?]**
166. Dealing with tum'ah of a woman who gives birth: **[?]**
167. Not eating kodshim if you're tamei: **[?]**
168. Women who gives birth brings a korban: Shekalim 6:5, Kinnim **[?]**
169. Dealing with tum'ah of a metzora: Large parts of Nega'im **[?]**
170. Not shaving the hair of a nesek: Nega'im **[?]**
171. Metzora having disheveled clothes and hair, and all temei'im making themselves known: Megillah 1:7, Nega'im **[?]**
172. Dealing with tum'ah of tzara'as on clothes: Nega'im **[?]**
173. Making a metzora tahor: Nega'im **[?]**
174. Shaving a metzora on the 7th day: Nega'im **[?]**
175. Temei'im using the mikvah: Mikva'os
176. Metzora bringing korbanos on becoming tahor: **[?]**
177. Dealing with tum'ah of tzara'as on houses: Nega'im **[?]**
178. Dealing with tum'ah of a zav: Zavim **[?]**
179. Zav bringing korbanos on becoming tahor: Kinnim/Zavim **[?]**
180. Dealing with tum'ah of semen: **[?]**
181. Dealing with tum'ah of a niddah: Niddah **[?]**
182. Dealing with tum'ah of a zavah: Niddah **[?]**
183. Zavah bringing korbanos on becoming tahor: Kinnim/Niddah **[?]**
184. Not going into the Beis Hamikdash except for avodah purposes: **[?]**
185. Doing the Yom Kippur avodah: Yoma 1-7
186. Not slaughtering kodshim outside the azarah: **[?]**
187. Covering the blood of wild animals or birds: Chulin **[?]**
188. Not doing things that lead to giluy arayos: **[?]**
189. Not having relations with your father: maybe Kerisos **[?]**
190. Not having relations with your mother: Yevamos 1:3 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
191. Not having relations with your father's wife: Yevamos 1:3 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
192. Not having relations with your sister: Yevamos 1:1, 1:3 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
193. Not having relations with your son's daughter: Yevamos 1:1 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
194. Not having relations with your daughter's daughter: Yevamos 1:1 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
195. Not having relations with your daughter: Yevamos 1:1 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
196. Not having relations with your sister from your father: Yevamos 1:3 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
197. Not having relations with your father's sister: Yevamos 1:3 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
198. Not having relations with your mother's sister: Yevamos 1:1 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
199. Not having relations with your father's brother: probably Kerisos **[?]**
200. Not having relations with your father's brother's wife: Yevamos 1:3 **[b]** probably a better one in Kerisos **[?]**
201. Not having relations with your daughter in law: Yevamos 1:1, 11:1, probably also Kerisos **[?]**
202. Not having relations with your brother's wife: Yevamos 4:2, probably also Kerisos **[?]**
203. Not having relations with your wife's mother or daughter: Yevamos 1:1, 11:1 probably also Kerisos **[?]**
204. Not having relations with your wife's son's daughter or father's mother: Yevamos 1:1, 11:1 probably also Kerisos **[?]**
205. Not having relations with your wife's daughter's daughter or mother's mother: Yevamos 1:1, 11:1 probably also Kerisos **[?]**
206. Not having relations with your wife's sister: Yevamos 1:1 and chapter 3, probably also Kerisos **[?]**
207. Not having relations with a niddah: Yevamos 3:3, Kesubos 7:6, Niddah, lots of other places
208. Not giving your kids to Molech: Megillah 4:9 **[b]**, probably other places too **[?]**
209. Men not having relations with a man: Probably Kerisos or Sanhedrin **[?]**
210. Men not having relations with an animal: Probably Kerisos or Sanhedrin **[?]**
211. Women not having relations with an animal: Probably Kerisos or Sanhedrin **[?]**

Comment: Nice work! For #6, aren't the mishnayos in Pesachim 8:3 (לעולם נמנין עליו עד שיהא בו כזית לכל אחד ואחד) and 8:7 (ואינן יכולין לאכול כזית אין שוחטין עליהן) sufficient?

Comment: @Meir Thank you!  Everyone has to be _able_ to eat a kezayis, but there's no explicit statement that you have to _actually_ eat a kezayis.  I'd rather err on the side of **[b]** so that people reading the answer can judge for themselves whether they want to count it or not.

Comment: At this rate, we're going to [run out of characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447) somewhere around mitzvah 450-500 (Re'eh-Shoftim).

Comment: @Heshy read kreisos 1

Answer (score 4):

The Rambam says all 613 are discussed in the Mishnah.

> וכאשר כלל הדעות והדברים החל לחבר המשנה שהיא כוללת פירוש כל המצות הכתובות בתורה.
>
> When [Rebbi] gathered together all the different opinions, he started to compose the Mishnah, which is an explanation of all of the mitzvos in the Torah.
>
> https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah.8.10

Comment: You probably forgot to add "metaphorically". It is very far from it.

Comment: @AlBerko It's possible that he doesn't mean it literally.  Do you have any evidence that that's the case?  Can you give an example that isn't discussed in the mishnah?

Comment: Where is Sefirat ha-Omer mentioned?

Comment: @DoubleAA while I'd love to go through the 613 and fact check it myself, I don't yet have enough bekius for that.  I should have figured you would.  I think you can count Chagiga 2:4 - it gives one halacha of Sefirah, that it doesn't always start on Sunday.  It's a slight stretch.

Comment: This isn't my discovery, but if I'm not mistaken counting the omer isn't mentioned by any Tanna ever. That mishna is just about calculating shavuot. Rambam thinks oral counting is a biblical command. (Remember https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83024/759 )

Comment: @DoubleAA once you assume, as Rambam does, that it is a biblical mitzvah, then one halacha of that mitzvah comes out of this mishnah.  (The same way the mishnah doesn't need to separately explain the issur melacha on the first day of Pesach, 7th day of Pesach, etc.)  It's a very good question on his opinion of Sefirah in general.  Once you answer that, it's an okay question on this statement in the Peirush Hamishnayos, but I think you can get out of it like I have here.  It's a judgment call and I definitely see your point.

Comment: @DoubleAA I can't think of a mishnah in Pesachim that explicitly says each individual has to eat the Pesach.  It describes how you eat it, the issur of nosar, and לא בא מתחילתו אלא לאכילה, and how you don't shecht it for someone who can't eat a kezayis or if there's not enough for everyone to have a kezayis.  But maybe, as long as I'm capable of eating a kezayis, I can just let the other people in the group eat the whole thing.

Comment: This sort of brings to light how this is a bit of an unclear question. The Mishna obviously doesn't say "here's the list of the 613 Mitzvos" as there are Machloksim through the Rishonim as to what the 613 even are. Things like 'Omer" and 'Korban Pesach' are definitely mentioned, but there are dozens of Mitzvos that are related to those, which may or may not be directly listed in the Mishnayos, so how do those get counted with regards to this exercise?

Comment: @Salmon Counting Omer is not mentioned. Shavuot is mentioned and the Korban Omer is mentioned.

Comment: @Salmononius2 This is not totally true, while there's small discrepancies, most everyday Mitzvos are unanimous, and still they are not mentioned as Mitzvos, like Teffilin, Bris Milah or Kri"Shmah.